# Can a Web Crawler follow links from <Link> tag in React?

Tags: web-crawlers, seo

I am building a frontend website and I am trying to make sure that the website can be crawled by search engines so that it can appear in search results.

Currently, most of my links look like this in react:

```
<Link to="/about" className="btn">More About Us</Link>
```

But Google says this:

> Google can follow links only if they are an  tag with an href attribute. Links that use other formats won't be followed by Google's crawlers. Google cannot follow  links without an href tag or other tags that perform a links because of script events.

Does this mean that my website will not crawled? Would the `sitemap.xml` be the solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [React documentation for `<Link>`](https://knowbody.github.io/react-router-docs/api/Link.html):

> `<Link>` will render a fully accessible anchor tag with the proper href.

In other words it renders a tag like `<a href=...>` which is compliant with what Googlebot expects.

Answer (score 0):

When you build that project in React, it will render as a standard HTML anchor link. If it's not server side rendered, Googlebot can still execute JavaScript and see your link.

So yes, Googlebot will crawl your links just fine.